# Retrieve pairs from a list that are within a certain time of one and another

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get groups that have a pair of items in it.

```
public enum eState
{
   On,
   Off,
   blah,
}

public class TestA
{
   public DateTime Time {get; set;}
   public eState State {get; set;}
}
```

If I have a list of TestA items.  If one if the item's state is On it will have a following Off.  There could be other items between the On and Off.  I need to get a list of pairs that are within 7 minutes of each other.

For instance if my List looked like:

```
1)  5/30/2014 8:30  | blah
2)  5/30/2014 8:32  | On 
3)  5/30/2014 8:33  | blah
4)  5/30/2014 8:34  | blah
5)  5/30/2014 8:35  | Off
6)  5/30/2014 8:36  | blah
7)  5/30/2014 8:37  | On
8)  5/30/2014 8:55  | blah
9)  5/30/2014 8:56  | Off
10) 5/30/2014 8:57  | On
11) 5/30/2014 8:58  | Off
12) 5/30/2014 8:59  | blah
```

It should return these Pairs:
2,5  and 10,11   both these on and off pairs are within 7 minutes of each other.
There will never be a situation where there is a off before a corresponding on.

Comment: Well, go ahead, do it.

Comment: Sounds like a simple iteration of the list would work; just keep track of when the last On you saw was - when you find the matching Off, yield the pair if the time difference is 7 minutes or less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not planning on using the `linq` expression against a `dataprovider` (database) I would recommend using a `for` loop to iterate the list.

Here is a `linq` implementation if you are still interested:

```
var query = from x in list
            from z in list.Where(y => y.State == eState.Off)
                          .Where(y => y.Time > x.Time)
                          .Where(y => y.Time <= x.Time.AddMinutes(7))
                          .OrderBy(y => y.Time)
                          .Take(1)
            where x.State == eState.On
            select new
            {
                 x, z
            };
```

Comment: Wouldn't the filtering take O(n²) time, as opposed to O(n) for a simple sweep?

Comment: @Douglas most likely if it is `linq-to-objects`. However its a whole different story if it is moved to `linq-to-entities`

Answer (score 1):

```
TestA lastOn = null;
int lastIndex = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < tests.Length; i++)
{
    switch (test[i].State)
    {
        case eState.On:
            if (lastOn == null)
            {
                lastOn = test[i];
                lastIndex = i;
            }
            break;

        case eState.Off:
            if (lastOn != null)
            {
               if (test[i].Time - lastOn.Time < TimeSpan.FromMinutes(7))
                   Console.WriteLine(lastIndex + "," + i);
               lastOn = null;
            }
            break;
    }       
}
```